# Binding a text to a Itemtemplate in a Gridview using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have a problem, i have a method using c# where i read in a long text which contains a pathway to a folder. And by breaking it down using regex i save a small text which i want to show in my gridview. The code looks like this

```
string folder = @"X:\05_General\T\TestVehicleInfo\Vehicles\Bordeaux_2099908\Readouts\All\20160126_22138km_RESF_Tw1602\After\XCOM\Bordeaux_2099908_20160128_22159km_XCOM_ALL_DTC_CDABX1.txt";
        string[] parts = folder.Split('\\');
        List<string> filteredstrings = new List<string>();
        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(part, @"\d{8}"))
            {
                filteredstrings.Add(part);
            }
        }
```

And the gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ReadOutID" HeaderText="ReadOutID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ReadOutID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FileTime" HeaderText="FileTime" SortExpression="FileTime" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ImportTime" HeaderText="ImportTime" SortExpression="ImportTime" />
                               <%--  <asp:BoundField DataField="FullPath" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="FullPath" />--%>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="FullPath">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FullPath") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# **What should i write here?**  %>'></asp:Label>


                                    </ItemTemplate>
```

I want to show the filteredsting in the asp:label area where i wrote "what should i write here". What command should i use?

Comment: Are you filling gridview from `DataTable`..?

Comment: Yes! From a SQL source

Comment: Since you Have List<string> which you want to show into gridview, right..??

Comment: you can use `Eval` <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text=' <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Your item")%>'  />

Comment: You can Add a column in `DataTable` and according to The rows, Just fill the new column with your string and then bind the `BoundField` usual way.

Comment: @KanisXXX, I can't edit the DataTable on my SQL Server.

Comment: @Priya, i don't quite understand. What should "your item" be? Should it be my FilteredStrings?

Comment: @AdnanHossain i mean to say get data from SQL server and put that into TEMP `DataTable` and then add column to that Temp Table, by doing this your actual data of Sql server will be not change

Comment: @KanisXXX please see below, i have written a code but it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have That string in your `Gridview` Row
on aspx, Then add `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound"` Event on gridview

and then try this code on code behind

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string folder = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;//Your gridview cell location of that string
            string[] parts = folder.Split('\\');
            List<string> filteredstrings = new List<string>();
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(part, @"\d{8}"))
                {
                    filteredstrings.Add(part);
                }
            }
            e.Row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() {Text = string.Join(",", filteredstrings)});// this will give CSV value of your List<string>
       }
   }
```

Hope This will help

Comment: glad i was able to help..Please check it as accepted answer :)